# Proper cascade delete

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There are 3 entities:

- User
- Event
- Review.

**User** has `ICollection<Event>` and `ICollection<Review>`.

**Event** has virtual User navigation property, and `ICollection<Review>`

Structure of **Review** class

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int Mark { get; set; }

    public ReviewStatus ReviewStatus { get; set; }

    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
```

And i got - Introducing FOREIGN KEY may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I can solve it by adding this on `ModelCreating` method of `DbContext`:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().
            HasMany(e => e.Reviews).
            WithRequired(e => e.Event).
            WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().
            HasMany(u => u.Reviews).
            WithRequired(r => r.User).
            WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But after this I can't delete Event or user from database, because foreign key error occurs. So is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide between not being able to delete or inserting null in places of foreign-key when you delete, you can let the `User` to be deleted and insert null for any deleted `Event` that was foreignkey in `Review` and have orphaned `Review`, here is the code for making `Event` to `Review` relationship nullable:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
           .HasOptional(t => t.Event)
           .WithMany(t => t.Reviews)
           .HasForeignKey(d => d.EventId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


           modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Event)
            .WithMany(p => p.Reviews)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.EventId);
```

also remember to lazy load the `Event` and `Review` with `Include` when deleting the user otherwise `null` will not get inserted, other point to make is that remember when you face situations like this when `User` have many `Events` and `Events` have many `Reviews` you have to do the null insertion for `Event` to `Review` yourself, EF doesn't do this for you, something like blow example:

```
var eventItems = _db.Events.Include(p => p.Reviews).(s => s.UserIdfk == UserId);

                foreach (var item in eventItems)
                {
                    _db.Events.Remove(item);
                }
```

I hope I've been able to convey the general approach.

Comment: Too often suggestions are made to make a foreign key nullable to solve a problem. What if your business model states a `Review` shouldn't exist without a `User`, it may not make sense for a `Review` to be a standalone entity. You could end up with loads of redundant `Review` entries. Even if you are unable to have a cascade delete rule you would then just write business logic to delete dependent Reviews when deleting the principal entity.

Comment: In this particular situation entity framework won't allow for both **user** and **event** to cascade their deletes to **review**, we can either don't allow deleting for one of them, which should be the top level entity in this case **user**, or null in place of it for child entity, IMHO if we don't want any of that we should change our entity design.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Cascade delete is not the only way to remove dependent entities. If you were deleting a `User` (top level), then you would load the `Events` and `Reviews` and put these in the `Deleted` state. It does seem overkill, but better than leaving 'possible' redundant data in the DB.

Comment: However, if you were just deleting an `Event` you wouldn't need to. As this as only one dependent relationship, you can set `WillCascadeOnDelete` to true.

Comment: @user2697817 You mean even if cascade delete is off by lazy load one related entity EF automatically delete the related one too? can you give me some link for more info on this?

Comment: No, you would need to manually remove it or put it in the deleted state. If a cascade rule was enabled but there was no corresponding database rule, then this is the way you would remove dependents.